# Website links behaving abnormally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made this website: http://manojpandey.tk/ implementing Bootstrap v.3

In the Contact section, I have added some social buttons.

```
<ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">
    <li>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/manojpandey96" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/manojpandey1996" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Facebook</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

They are showing some abnormal behaviour that I don't get. When someone clicks on the button directly, a blank webpage with same url opens. Opening in new tab does good.

But, why does the former does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="http://twitter.com/manojpandey96" target="_top"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
```

Works for me. So just add:

```
target="_top"
```

to the a-Tags.

Is there a reason why you are using frames?

**Edit:**
The Frames are causing the problem. Without adding target, the link usually will open within the frame. But if you add target="_top", then it will be loaded in the full window, ignoring the frames.
More detailed explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Beginner at html/css. Don't know much stuff :P

Comment: One more help: How to get acquainted with HTML/CSS as a beginner?

Comment: For me this a question like: How have you learned to speak? Answer: I can't remember 100% how I learned it. The very basic stuff you can learn here: http://www.codecademy.com/en
After that you could try to create a website from scratch. Using bootstrap is nice; I use it too. But you'll learn much more doing it by yourself. (try & error gave me most of my knowledge and experience.  And asking others if you are stuck and can't find an answer.). And now I'm still learning HTML, CSS, etc. just by answering such questions ;-) This also help me alot.
And one more thing: Please avoid using frames.